# MFC DialogBased

Tags: visual-c++, unicode

When to use `_TCHAR` char types? `_T(_TEXT)` and `L` macros? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

The `TCHAR` type, the `TEXT` and `_T` macros are meant for code that compiles as both unicode and non-unicode builds.

- If you configure your project as unicode, `TCHAR` is a typedef to `wchar_t`, otherwise it is just `char`.
- The `L` in front of a string literal (e.g. `L"Test"`) instructs the compiler that the constant is meant to be a unicode string.
- The `TEXT` and `_T` macros both do insert this L in front of the literal if the project is build as unicode. `TEXT("Test")` is `L"Test"` in unicode builds, otherwise just `"Test"`.

When calling library functions such as win32 API calls or the C runtime library, you always have to call the character-type-agnostic version of a function call, e.g. `_tcslen` instead of `strlen` or `wcslen`.

Examples:

```
// Non-unicode build
const char* str = "Hello, World";
size_t len = strlen( str );

// Unicode build
const wchar_t* str = L"Hello, World";
size_t len = wcslen( str );

// Works with both
const TCHAR* str = _T("Hello, World");
size_t len = _tcslen( str );
```